# php cli on linux not working

Tags: php, command-line-interface

PHP CLI has suddently stopped working on the server. When running any php file even php -v to get php version I get following error.

Thanks

```
# php -v
Unknown option: v
php [-f from_encoding] [-t to_encoding] [-s string] [files...]
php -l
php -r encoding_alias
  -l,--list
     lists all available encodings
  -r,--resolve encoding_alias
    resolve encoding to its (Encode) canonical name
  -f,--from from_encoding
     when omitted, the current locale will be used
  -t,--to to_encoding
     when omitted, the current locale will be used
  -s,--string string
     "string" will be the input instead of STDIN or files
The following are mainly of interest to Encode hackers:
  -D,--debug          show debug information
  -C N | -c | -p      check the validity of the input
  -S,--scheme scheme  use the scheme for conversion
```

Comment: Check your search path for anything calling itself php that isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `which php` on your shell to find which `php` executable your shell picks from your search `PATH`.

Use `ls -l $(which php)` to see if it's a symlink to some other executable.

What you see when running `php -v` is actually output of the `piconv` command.

Most possibly, there is a symlink named `php` pointing to `piconv` somewhere in your search `PATH`.

Type `echo $PATH` to see the order of directories in which your shell searches for an executable `php`.

EDIT:
Changed `whereis` to `which` in the command above.

Comment: Tried doing which php. I get following 

    []# which php
    /usr/bin/php

    []# ls -l $(which php)
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5843 Sep  3  2010 /usr/bin/php

    []# echo $PATH
    /usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin


Seems like there is no symlink and its pointing to the right php cli.

:confused

Comment: @user1280545: whats the output of `/usr/bin/php -v`? if its the same then possibly someone (you?) has overwritten the `php` binary with the content of `piconv`. If you edit that file you should see some perl code.

Comment: Yes I think that's the case. I just did /usr/bin/php -v and got the same output then did nano /use/bin/php and found ipconv perl code inside the file. How can I mend this now and place php cli back in place. I have no idea how that happened.... BTW, really appreciate your help so far

Comment: @user1280545 if you appreciate the help, please click on the arrow beside this answer to vote it up and click the checkmark to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @user1280545: "fixing" this issue depends on the linux distribution you use. On a APT based linux (debian, ubuntu) you can simply issue `sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-cli` to reinstall the whole package, overwriting the original files. On a yum based linux (redhat, fedora, suse, centos, ..) you can follow the second option of this guide: http://hacktux.com/yum/force/reinstall

Comment: ok just quickly read the link sent over. I have plesk control panel installed on server and a few critical websites. just wondering if it will break anything within plesk or generally on the server.

Comment: @user1280545 it *SHOULD* not break anything in the long term. (for a short period during the reinstall, PHP may be unavailable/malfunctioning)